# COM Interface as a param of WinRT ref class, how it possible?

Tags: class, com, interface, windows-runtime, param

How I can define this class correctly:

```
public ref class WICBMP sealed
{
  void Load(IWICBitmapSource ^wicBitmapSource);
};
```

Comment: There's no point in trying, your app won't pass the Store validation.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  Only Windows Runtime types may be used when declaring members of a Windows Runtime interface (in this specific case, the compiler will need to generate an interface that declares your `Load` member function).  You can't even do this if you try to define the interface in IDL.

A runtime class can *implement* COM interfaces that are not Windows Runtime interfaces, though.  For example, see [`IBufferByteAccess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846267.aspx) (a COM interface), which all [`IBuffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh438362.aspx) (a Windows Runtime interface) implementations must implement.

Comment: Thank you, James. Of course, I can't use such declaration, as I wrote. But may be I can use something as ComPtr, to "transfer" interface from an application to the library component?

Comment: Yes, you can do something similar to what is done with `IBuffer` and `IBufferByteAccess`, as noted in the answer.  Write a class that implements a Windows Runtime interface for identity and a COM interface to provide access to the `IWICBitmapSource`.  Your WinRT components can use `IMyWinRTInterface` to refer to it in their public API surface, then can QueryInterface for the COM interface to get the actual `IWICBitmapSource`.

Comment: I can provide an example of this on Monday, if you'd like.